# Get only HTML code out from a PHP file using PHP?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a PHP file, I needed to get the HTML code only for send email. where I use `file_get_contents(email.php);` it also get the php code is there are any way i can get only HTML out?

```
<?php 
   $pid=20;
   $cid=30;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Promotion Email</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <p><?php $pid + $cid ?></p>
</body>
```

I need only **HTML** I tried to get like this:

```
$body = file_get_contents("promotion-mail-contents.php");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just call it like from external.

```php
$body = file_get_contents("http://www.yourdomain.com/promotion-mail-contents.php");
```